# Customizing model metadata data annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Is there any way to add a custom data annotation for metadata? I find than [DefaultValue] doesn't work

```
namespace PROJECT.Common.Attributes
{
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MyDefaultValueAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware 
{
    public string DefaultValue;

    private dynamic _DefaultValue; 

    public MyDefaultValueAttribute(string m_value_tx)
    {
        _DefaultValue = m_value_tx; 
    }

    public MyDefaultValueAttribute(bool m_default_yn)
    {
        _DefaultValue = m_default_yn;
    }

    public MyDefaultValueAttribute(Int32 m_default_no)
    {
        _DefaultValue = m_default_no;
    }

    public MyDefaultValueAttribute(DateTime m_default_dt)
    {
        _DefaultValue = m_default_dt;
    }

    public MyDefaultValueAttribute(decimal m_defaul_tx)
    {
        _DefaultValue = m_defaul_tx;
    }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AdditionalValues["DefaultValue"] = _DefaultValue;

    }
}
```

and on i created a model binder but the problem is, the data annotation that i make only works for string..

i am passing dynamic on my constructor...

any help is appreciated... I clearly want custom annotations

THANKS

Comment: `ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues` is a `Dictionary<string, object>` so its always stored as `object`.  Your implementation does not make much sense since default values should be initialised in constructors

Comment: from the first look - may be you are looking for generics and attributes ? reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173129.aspx

Comment: Using that type of constructors, i created a custom annotation for string cases such as Uppercase lower and title case... But trying in default value, it doesn't. the way i defined my constructor is because when i used my own data annotation for default value, it only works for strings. Thanks